# How can I getDocuments from a subcollection in Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get all of the data from a subcollection in Firestore in Swift. Currently, my firestore structure has a series of courses, which are documents, each of which have a collection of cards inside them. I want to access the cards of a certain course.

I'm able to get the correct course but the "document.reference.collection("cards").getDocuments()" part of my code doesn't seem to be getting anything, as my "subSnapshot" always turns up empty.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
static func getCourseCards(courseTitle: String) async throws -> [[String:Any]] {
        let store = Firestore.firestore()
        var courseCards: [[String:Any]] = []
        
        
        do {
            let snapshot =  try await store.collection("courses").whereField("Title", isEqualTo: courseTitle).getDocuments()
            
            for document in snapshot.documents {
                print("1", document.data())
                print(document.reference)
                let subSnapshot = try await document.reference.collection("cards").getDocuments()
                
                for document in subSnapshot.documents {
                    print("2")
                    print(document.data())
                    courseCards.append(document.data())
                }
                
                
            }
            
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
        
        print("3", courseCards)
        return courseCards
    }
```

Where am I going wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an empty result because you don't have a top-level collection called "cards".

You need to identify the full path of the subcollection, including the top-level collection "courses", the nesting document "States and mottoes", and the nested subcollection "cards".

There is an example in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_subcollection).

```
let snapshot =  try await store
    .collection("courses/States and mottoes/cards")
    .whereField("Title", isEqualTo: courseTitle)
    .getDocuments()
```

If you are trying to get all documents from all subcollections called cards, no matter where they are nested, then you need a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Comment: But I want to dynamically select which course the cards are being pulled from, instead of strictly typing the full path "courses/States and mottoes/cards". I thought that I was getting that path with "document.reference" after first querying for the course document.

Should I just get that path string with something like .collection("courses/\(courseTitle)/cards")?

Comment: Do whatever you need to do to build the full path.  You can't locate and query the subcollection without it.